# Make the item active when a media request is made

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   #media_wrapper {
    height: 100%; //// ?????
    display: inline-block;
   }
}
#media_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

As you can see, the element is not active for large screens `display: none;`, but I do not know how to correctly set the display attribute in the query to display on a small screen, after trying for example: `block` or `inline-block`, the result is one - nothing is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have this meta in you head : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: yes, <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: you should define a height. try changing to pixels.

Comment: but i have a wrapper @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){ 
}
.media_container{
  height: 100%;
  position: relative
}
#media_wrapper{
 height:100%;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**best way is to change the order of command:**

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/17d6hxsL/5/

```css
#media_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   #media_wrapper {
    display: block;
   }
}

.wrapper{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="media_wrapper">
Hello
</div>
</div>
```

**Or you should set  `!important`  to pervent override:**

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/17d6hxsL/4/

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   #media_wrapper {
    display: block!important;
   }
}
#media_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.wrapper{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="media_wrapper">
Hello
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you you saved my life) . block!important; is working

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Check Demo **[HERE](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/yEwxqz)**

> Reverse it

CSS:

```
#media_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   #media_wrapper {
    height: 100%; 
    display: inline-block;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Romikromikromik Your Welcome.. :) but remember `always declare the media queries at the bottom of stylesheet` and avoid usage of `!important` as much as possible